# do we need to implement connection pooling for google cloud datastore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-datastore

i have a basic question with respect to google's cloud datastore

I am implementing a rails application where several models are based on googles cloud datastore. In the google example code, the model class initiates a new connection to the datastore every time. Do we need to implement connection pooling or is this way different from sql database connection management. It seems perfectly acceptable to initiate and tear down connections every time the model is read/written (from what little documentation help is available on this subject).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Datastore has two interfaces RPC and REST. Both of them are stateless protocols. So, independently from library that you are using to make requests they are not keeping persistent connection, but instead firing requests again and again. So, I guess the answer will be no, you don't need to.